# How to redirect filename.php to /friendly-url for the same filename.php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, devops, friendly-url

I have link to filename.php in my site. I want that when someone enters this page via the example.com/filename.php it will redirect him (301) to example.com/friend-url and display the content of filename.php

I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Redirect 301 /filename.php$ /furl
RewriteRule ^furl$ /filename.php
```

But the page isn't loading at all.

Comment: Did you enable ` RewriteEngine On` ?

Comment: its on.. I want to chane filename.php to /friendly-url for seo and without changing the actual link in the code. is it possible?

Comment: what's the point on redirecting ? if you are on the same domain just change the url and display the same content `RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^furl/?$    filename.php    [NC,L]` also rewrite is enabled on your server?

Comment: _“I want to chane filename.php to /friendly-url for seo and without changing the actual link in the code. is it possible?”_ - it makes little sense. Such a redirect from “ugly” URLs to pretty ones is justified for links on external pages, that you have no control over. But on your own page, you should really modify your links, so that you are using the pretty URLs directly. Adding an additional redirect is going to slow things down. Not necessarily in a way that a human would immediately notice - but speed is a ranking factor to Google these days, and you won’t win any points there with this.